# Why is SoS 8.5 ‘dē dēsertō’ not interpreted as ‘from the forsaken’?

Tags: vulgata, late-latin, bible

## Sources and translations

Vulgate 8.5 opens with this passages:

> Quæ est ista quæ ascendit dē dēsertō, dēliciīs affluēns,
>  innīxa super dīlēctum suum?

This is rendered in the 2011 translation to Norwegian as:

> Kven er ho som stig opp frå ørkenen,
>  stødd til kjærasten?
> Who is she who rises up from the desert,
>  leaning on to [her] lover?

Liebeschuetz and Hill (2005: 397) render the phrase in question as:

> Let us also believe, as others have it, that *he has ascended from the desert*, that is to say from this arid and untilled place to that region of flowering delights, where united with his brother he enjoys the pleasure of eternal life.
> [Italicisation in original.]

From the original Latin:

> Crēdāmus et sīcut aliī habeat, quia *ascendit ā dēsertō,* […]

**I, however, ended up translating it as such:**

> Who is she who ascends from this forsaken [place], overflowing with pleasure,
>  leaning on her beloved?

## Dictionary entries

All dictionary entries seem to agree that the masculine participle means something abandoned, deserted or forsaken, and that to mean the literal desert, one needed the substantivised neuter which apparently only existed in the plural.

### *Cassell’s Latin Dictionary*

> **dēsertus** -a -um, p[articipial] adj[jective], with compar. and superl. (desero), *forsaken, abandoned, deserted;* locus, regio, Cic.: loca, Caes.; deserta siti regio, Sall. Subst., **dēserta** -ōrum, n. *deserts, wildernesses,* verg.

### *Latinsk ordbok*

> **dēserō** […] **-sertus**, ᴀᴅᴊ. ᴘ. ᴛʀ. ɢʀ. *forlatt, ubebodd, øde;* locus; solitudo d-sima; vicus; arbores *(enslige, enkeltstående),* [S.] P[ro]p[er]t[ius] **-serta**, -ōrum, ɴ. ᴘʟ. *ørken, ødemark;* Libyae, ferarum, [P.] V[ergilius Maro].
> **dēserō** […] **-sertus**, ᴀᴅᴊ. ᴘ. ᴛʀ. ɢʀ. *abandoned, uninhabited, desolate;* locus; solitudo d-sima; vicus; arbores *(single, isolated/detached),* [S.] P[ro]p[er]t[ius] **-serta**, -ōrum, ɴ. ᴘʟ. *desert, wilderness;* Libyae, ferarum, [P.] V[ergilius Maro].

### Lewis and Short

> **dēsertus** , a, um, Part. and P. a., from desero.

> **dē-sĕro** , rŭi, rtum, 3, v. a. Lit.,
> I.to *undo* or *sever* one's connection with another; hence, with esp. reference to the latter, *to leave, forsake, abandon, desert, give up* (cf. derelinquere; more restricted in signif. than relinquere, which denotes, in general, to depart from, to leave any one. Deserere, orig. in milit. lang., implies a cowardly running away; frequently used with prodere; also in the flg. phrase: deserere vitam; and later, *absol.* in the sense of *to desert*, etc.; cf. also: linquere, destituere, deficere, discedere—freq. and class.).
> I. Lit. […] B. Absol., in milit. lang., *to desert,* […]
> II. Trop. […] B. Since the Aug. per. *subst.*: dēserta , ōrum, n., *desert places, deserts, wastes,*

## Question

All dictionaries I have checked seem to agree that to indicate desert as a place, it should be neuter plural; I would have expected the Latin to be *dē dēsertīs*, not *dē dēsertō*. I understand L&H to have based their rendering of the Bible verse on the Bible translation, as it is italicised. So to my understanding, it is the translations of the Bible which have chosen the literal identification of *dē dēsertō* to mean *from the desert*, rather than allowing for a figurative translation which we can get from *from the deserted place*, *from the desolate place* or even more so from *from the forsaken place*. (I chose to add *this* in my translation, as it flowed better in English.)

**Why do all of these translations choose the literal and seemingly wrong (or imprecise) *from the desert* rather than the figurative *from the deserted, abandoned, desolate* as translation of *dē dēsertō*?**

## Literature

- Ambrosius, Aurēlius: [Dē Obitū Valentīniānī Cōnsōlātiō](https://www.documentacatholicaomnia.eu/04z/z_0339-0397__Ambrosius__De_Obitu_Valentiniani_Consolatio__MLT.pdf.html).
- [*Bibelen*, *Høgsongen* kapittel 8](https://bibel.no/Nettbibelen?slang=nynorsk11&query=tVFiwZV%20wf1sroCiFQzYHy0yjfgpJy0WG49chqcCc0k/kEZHgXO5KUn66ab%20U%20UV).
- Johanssen, Jan & Nygaard, Marius & Schreiner, Emil: *Latinsk ordbok*, fourth revised edition by Egil Kraggerud and Bjørg Tosterud, Cappelen, Oslo 1998.
- Liebeschuetz, John Hugo Wolfgang Gideon; Hill, Carole; Ambrŏsius, Aurēlius: *Ambrose of Milan*, *Translated Texts for Historians* 43, Liverpool University Press, Liverpool, 2005.
- [Lewis, Charlton T. and Short, Charles: *A Latin Dictionary*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddesero2)
- Marchant, J. R. V., M. A. & Charles, Joseph F., B. A.: *Cassell’s Latin Dictionary : Latin–English and English–Latin*, 24th edition revised by Marchant and Charles, Cassell and Company, London, Toronto and Melbourne, February 1946.
- [*Vulgata*, *Song of Songs* chapter 8](https://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/vul/sol008.htm#005).

Answer (score 8):

> All dictionaries I have checked seem to agree that to indicate desert as a place, it should be neuter plural; I would have expected the Latin to be dē dēsertīs, not dē dēsertō.

In Classical Latin, perhaps, but you have to keep reading the full entry.

> B. Since the Aug. per. subst.: dēserta , ōrum, n., desert places, deserts, wastes, Verg. E. 6, 81; id. G. 3, 342; Plin. 5, 4, 4, § 26 al.—With gen.: “Libyae deserta,” Verg. A. 1, 384; so id. G. 3, 291; Front. Strat. 1, 7, 7; Vulg. Isa. 52, 9 al.—**In sing.: dēsertum , i, n. (eccl. Lat.): “in deserto,” Prud. Apoth. 774; Hier. Ep. 125, 2; Vulg. Num. 1, 1; Luc. 3, 2 et saep.**

I note in particular the "eccl. Lat." part, i.e. Christian Latin, which includes the Vulgate. For what it's worth, the Latin also reflects the singular of the Hebrew הַמִּדְבָּ֔ר.

Comment: I cannot understand how I missed that. Now to make this a _really_ interesting answer, how come eccl. Latin changed the usage of the word? Is it due to what @Asteroides says above (https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/9/asteroides)?

Comment: I believe the reason I missed it, probably was confirmation bias. I rechecked both my paper dictionaries, and indeed there is no entry on ecclesiastical usage there. I simply didn’t expect there to be any new information after the Augustan entry, and did not notice. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: @CannedMan I assume indeed that since Jerome was translating from the Hebrew, he chose the singular. I'm not sure if it appears before the Vulgate (Prudentius was his contemporary), but it's a plausible origin to it.